# I want to spawn squares with different movement angle. Idk how to describe this, but I've got a video of how this should work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am a beginner to unity and wanted to learn smth new, so I decided to make a clone of this game
https://www.pinterest.ru/pin/499618152412280381/

Almost everything is done, but unfortunately, I can't find out how do I spawn these squares with.. uh.. random rotation angle? Bruh I can't explain it better. So this is the script that I have:

```
private void SpawnDefaultCube()
{
    GameObject a = Instantiate(defaultCube) as GameObject;
    a.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-screenBounds.x, screenBounds.x), screenBounds.y * 2, Camera.main.transform.position.z+1);
}

private void SpawnScoreCube()
{
    GameObject b = Instantiate(scoreCube) as GameObject;
    b.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-screenBounds.x, screenBounds.x), screenBounds.y * 2, Camera.main.transform.position.z+1);
}
```

Now the cubes are falling down, but I want them to fall like in the video. What can I make to do so? Is there some kind of function? Thanks in advance, I've been struggling with this for several days now.

Comment: I actually found this code
`GameObject a = Instantiate(defaultCube) as GameObject;
    a.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-screenBounds.x, screenBounds.x), screenBounds.y * 2, Camera.main.transform.position.z+1);`
in youtube, so I don't even know how this works xD

Comment: I can't see the video .. could you explain better what you want to achieve?

Answer (score -1):

In the update of your cube, you could use `Transform.Rotate`.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html

For the random element of it, get a random number between -1 and 1 and multiply the rotation speed you decide with it.